# Not getting value of text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate my inputs using Jquery. Partial code, which is relevant to question is below. Don't worry about clicking to individual that's the other option. But I need to get text value in alert and hence show add button when the field is not blank. I cant change HTML as it is generated by Django.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rad_ind = $("label:contains('Individual')");
  var rad_com = $("label:contains('Company')");
  var co_name = $("#id_emp_coname").closest("p");
  var add_button = $("[value^='Add']");

  $("p:has(input)").hide();
  add_button.hide();


  rad_com.click(function() {
    $("p:has(input)").hide();
    co_name.show();
    co_name.change(function() {
      alert(co_name.val());
      if (co_name.val() == null || co_name.val() == "") {
        add_button.hide();
      } else {
        add_button.show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="id_ind_or_company_0">Is employer an individual or company:</label>
  <ul id="id_ind_or_company">
    <li>
      <label for="id_ind_or_company_0">
        <input id="id_ind_or_company_0" name="ind_or_company" type="radio" value="True" />Individual</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="id_ind_or_company_1">
        <input id="id_ind_or_company_1" name="ind_or_company" type="radio" value="False" />Company</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="id_emp_coname">Company Name:</label>
  <input id="id_emp_coname" maxlength="87" name="emp_coname" type="text" />
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
```

My question is why I am not getting the text value with .val()

I am getting blank alert. And therefore the add(submit) button does not work as expected. Can somebody tell me where am I making a mistake.

I know there are tons of pages on this and have been reading but cant find out what mistake I am doing.

Thanks,

Krishan

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` ? Do you find any errors in `console` ?

Comment: co_name = $("#id_emp_coname").closest("p"); will select the p tag closest to the input element. & that does not has a value attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use .val() on the input, not on the closest p element.

Try

```
$("#id_emp_coname").val();
```

I tested on a CodePen and it worked, change this on your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rad_ind = $("label:contains('Individual')");
  var rad_com = $("label:contains('Company')");
  var co_name = $("#id_emp_coname"); //Changed here
  var add_button = $("[value^='Add']");

  $("p:has(input)").hide();
  add_button.hide();


  rad_com.click(function() {
        $("p:has(input)").hide();
        co_name.show();
        co_name.change(function() {
          alert(co_name.val());
          if (co_name.val() == null || co_name.val() == "") {
            add_button.hide();
          } else {
            add_button.show();
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Got it. Silly mistake. Tag <p> has multiple elements and its not text field. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the value in alert you have to use val() like this

```
var co_nameValue = $("#id_emp_coname").val()
alert(co_nameValue );
```

Or you can do it in another way 
If you only  want to show the text box value in alert then simply on button click use

```
alert( $("#id_emp_coname").val());
```

Be sure that jQuery is included.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rad_ind = $("label:contains('Individual')");
  var rad_com = $("label:contains('Company')");
  var co_name = $("#id_emp_coname").closest("p");
  var add_button = $("[value^='Add']");

  $("p:has(input)").hide();
  add_button.hide();


  rad_com.click(function() {
    $("p:has(input)").hide();
    co_name.show();
    co_name.change(function() {
      input = co_name.find("#id_emp_coname"); // added this
      alert(input.val());
      if (input.val() == null || input.val() == "") { // changed this
        add_button.hide();
      } else {
        add_button.show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="id_ind_or_company_0">Is employer an individual or company:</label>
  <ul id="id_ind_or_company">
    <li>
      <label for="id_ind_or_company_0">
        <input id="id_ind_or_company_0" name="ind_or_company" type="radio" value="True" />Individual</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="id_ind_or_company_1">
        <input id="id_ind_or_company_1" name="ind_or_company" type="radio" value="False" />Company</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="id_emp_coname">Company Name:</label>
  <input id="id_emp_coname" maxlength="87" name="emp_coname" type="text" />
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
```

I would suggest you to use `var co_name = $("#id_emp_coname");` this solution mentioned by @leofontes, if that variable is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you try to get value from 'P' tag  $("#id_emp_coname").closest("p"), 
It is wrong methord. Please try with below code.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var rad_ind = $("label:contains('Individual')");
var rad_com = $("label:contains('Company')");
var co_name = $("#id_emp_coname");
var add_button = $("[value^='Add']");

$("#pCompanyName").hide();
add_button.hide();

rad_com.click(function() {
    $("#pCompanyName").show();
    co_name.change(function() {
        // alert(co_name.val());
        console.log(co_name.val());
        if (co_name.val() == null || co_name.val() == "") {
            add_button.hide();
        } else {
            add_button.show();
        }
    });
});
rad_ind.click(function() {
    $("#pCompanyName").hide();
    co_name.val("");
    add_button.hide();
  });
});
```

Html

```
        <p>
            <label for="id_ind_or_company_0">Is employer an individual
                or company:</label>
        <ul id="id_ind_or_company">
            <li><label for="id_ind_or_company_0"> <input
                    id="id_ind_or_company_0" name="ind_or_company" type="radio"
                    value="True" />Individual
            </label></li>
            <li><label for="id_ind_or_company_1"> <input
                    id="id_ind_or_company_1" name="ind_or_company" type="radio"
                    value="False" />Company
            </label></li>
        </ul>
        </p>
        <p id="pCompanyName">
            <label for="id_emp_coname">Company Name:</label> <input
                id="id_emp_coname" maxlength="87" name="emp_coname" type="text" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
```

Comment: But this requires change in html. I mentioned that I cannot change html as it is generated by Django.

Comment: Friend,  only a single change in html put a id attribute to 'P' tag.

Comment: Without any change please get value like this, 
          alert($("#id_emp_coname").val());
          if ($("#id_emp_coname").val() == null || $("#id_emp_coname").val() == "") {
            add_button.hide();
          } else {
            add_button.show();
          }